# floc and RETSIGTYPE in make source

Tags: c, include

Where do the keywords `floc` and `RETSIGTYPE` come from in the following extract of this C [code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/src/commands.h)?

```
struct commands
{
    floc fileinfo;              /* Where commands were defined.  */
    char *commands;             /* Commands text.  */
    char **command_lines;       /* Commands chopped up into lines.  */
    unsigned char *lines_flags; /* One set of flag bits for each line.  */
    unsigned short ncommand_lines;/* Number of command lines.  */
    char recipe_prefix;         /* Recipe prefix for this command set.  */
    unsigned int any_recurse:1; /* Nonzero if any 'lines_flags' elt has */
                                /* the COMMANDS_RECURSE bit set.  */
};

/* ... */

RETSIGTYPE fatal_error_signal (int sig);
```

This is one of the files in the **make** repository. I am wondering: since this `.h` file does not include any other header file, how can they be used here?

Comment: Where is the header being included? (Meaning, what file is including the header?)It might be that the header is included in a place where flog and retsigtype are defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbols you are asking for are defined in the following way:

```
#ifndef RETSIGTYPE
# define RETSIGTYPE     void
#endif

/* Specify the location of elements read from makefiles.  */
typedef struct
{
    const char *filenm;
    unsigned long lineno;
    unsigned long offset;
} floc;
```

Both definitions are contained by file `makeint.h`.

The reason why in `commands.h` these symbols are "visible" even if it doesn't include any header file is simply because every `*.c` file including it (for example `commands.c`) include `makeint.h` as well **before** it.

---

### How to find an answer in similar situations

I'm not an expert of the project you linked. I just

1. Cloned the project with `git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/make.git`
2. Created a project with a good source code browser (I used **SourceInsight**)
3. Searched for the symbols you were asking for and jumped to their definitions